# How to display search query in view's results page?

Tags: 7, views

I'm using views 3 with drupal 7.

I have a views page listing content of a certain content type 'Clothes'. I have a exposed form(in a block) that filters this list by size(small,medium,large) and color(red,blue).

When I click submit, is it possible to show in the header of my results page like the following?

> Showing results for Small size and Red color:

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ultimately all the filters send the data using HTTP methods GET/POST. If you are not using AJAX with views then HTTP method GET is used to send the data.

To display the information in header add *Global:Custom Text field* and add below line in it.

```
<div>Showing results for $_GET[X] size and $_GET[Y] color.</div>
```

Where : X - name of size field
        Y - name of color field
You will get the names from the url generated after search in address bar.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a simple way of doing this with *exposed* filters. *Contextual* filters, or arguments, on the other hand, have an option for this, that allows you to use tokens to set the title like

> Showing results for [size] size and [color] color

but that would on the other hand require you to find a different way of showing the exposed filters.

The easiest way I can think of to solve this, is to have *both* exposed and contextual filters. After that a form submit hook could do

```
$path_to_view = 'store/';
drupal_goto($path_to_view . $_GET['id_of_filter_1'] . '/' . $_GET['id_of_filter_2']);
```

to create a redirect from the exposed filters to the contextual ones. This way you could get the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this will help you or not but you can try this, For the title of the expose filter result you can try to add in between  `Global: Result summary`  or `Global: Text area` from `add header`
and the expose filter call the `views_exposed_form` on result use the

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id=='views_exposed_form')
    {
        $form['#submit'][] = 'call_ur_form_state_function';
    }   
}

function call_ur_form_state_function($form, &$form_state){
    //dpm($form_state);
}
```

to alter the `$form_state` value, there you will get the all array and object of the current view to alter, by this way probably you can reconstruct your string for output page.